# MySQLi not working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I know this question is pretty frequent but I wasted so much time on this and still it doesn't work. We're trying to insert a row but it just doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    class DAL{
        private $srvname='localhost';
        private $username='i110546';
        private $password='2349058';
        private $bdname='i110546';

        function insert_log($url){

            $conn = new mysqli($srvname, $username, $password, $bdname);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Conexao falhada: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                                return NULL;
            }

                        $query = "INSERT INTO `log` (`url`) VALUES (?)";
                        $test = $conn->prepare($query);
                        $test->bind_param('ss',$url);
                        $test->execute();
                        $test->close();
                        $conn->close();
                }
    }
?>
```

Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test->bind_param('ss',$url);
```

You're binding two two strings (ss) but only supplying one, while your statement only contains one placeholder, my guess is that your desired line is

```
$test->bind_param('s',$url);
```

Also, you're addressing your properties the wrong way, they need to be addressed using $this->variable_name inside methods (functions) so modify your line to this

```
$conn = new mysqli($this->srvname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->bdname);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. 500 Internal Server Error and I don't seem to find anyhting wrong besides that.

Comment: Are you suppressing errors? If so, then display them. It's possible that you're suppressing a fatal error which cannot be displayed and thus you're getting a 500 internal server error.

Comment: I'm not doing anything like that since I don't know how to do it in the first place.

Comment: Put these two lines at the top of your page, run it and see if you get any errors  `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: It says that the $srvanme, $username, bla bla is undefined.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a new fix.

Comment: I would kiss you but that would be awkward.

Comment: You could always accept my answer as the correct one if you don't fancy smooching

Answer (score 0):

You have only one parameter, but in your bind call you have 2 strings parameter `ss`.

Should be one:

```
$test->bind_param('s',$url);
```

And check for errors.

Comment: Still doesn't work. 500 Internal Server Error and I don't seem to find anyhting wrong besides that.